# Page won't scroll in any browser--am I using outdated CSS?

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

It's been about five years since I really got hands-deep into CSS coding, so I may be using outdated codes; however, everything seems to work fine but the scroll bar. Although I can add scroll bars to any div element I create, it won't allow the page to scroll. I've tried adding the overflow: auto; and overflow: scroll; options to my body tag but nothing works. I've included the coding I'm using as well, but I've double and triple checked that I haven't included another set of scroll tags. Can anyone see what the problem is? I'm afraid my CSS might be out of date, but everywhere I look says to just use the overflow tags. Thanks!
Also, the content element is set to be longer than the page so I can see if my scroll bar works, but adding overflow: scroll; to my body tag makes a scrollbar appear but not function.

CODING:

```
<style>
body{background: #000000; font-family: tahoma;}

#content{position: fixed; top: 155px; left: 347px; overflow: auto;}

.content{height: 800px; width: 506px; color: #FFFFFF; overflow: auto;}

#navigation{position: fixed; top: 155px; left: 153px;}

.navigation{height: 643px; width: 184px; background: #000000;}

a:link{display: block; background: #A70000; font-family: tahoma; font-size: 14pt; text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF; border-left: 3px #D50000 solid; width: 

180px; height: 25px; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 4px; text-indent: 6pt;}

a:hover{display: block; background: #A70000; font-family: tahoma; font-size: 14pt; text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; border-left: 3px #D50000 solid; 

width: 180px; height: 25px; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 4px; text-indent: 6pt;}
</style>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is the typical way to show and experiment with HTML/CSS/JS.  Set up a JS-fiddle and people can help you debug.

Comment: I created one, but I'm not even sure if I did that right. Like I said, it's been forever since I've tried to do something like this. I'm really sorry about that. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fMhCQ/)

Comment: i think the problem may come from position:fixed, since that locks your div onto the users viewport but I can't be sure with your case until the page is setup in jsfiddle.

Comment: So, instead of position:fixed, I need to use position:relative?

Comment: On the jsfiddle, I included the actual coding I'm using to create the website as well--hope that helps.

Comment: The update fiddle solves the problem.  Move the img to the end... that helps the content scroll under it.  You'll need to extend the image and maybe place it in a div so that it covers the entire region above the text.  Please vote on the answer if it solved your problem. thx

Comment: I found the problem. There *was* a fixed div that contained the one page that didn't scroll. Somehow it contained the one page but not the other. Yikes. Good call you guys.

Answer (score 5):

The issue appears to be with position: fixed;

position: relative would allow the content to scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/fMhCQ/13/